# Access to MethodInfo in OperationInterceptor

Tags: openrasta

I created a couple of custom attributes that I attach to my methods in the handlers. The custom attributes are more than mere 'taggers' like e.g. 'RequiresAuthenticationAttribute'. A simplified example:

```
[EnforceParam("Account")]
```

In my interceptor, that gets called for methods annotated with EnforceParam, I'd like to get access to the value "Account". What I'm currently doing for that is this:

```
public override bool BeforeExecute(IOperation operation)
{
    ReflectionBasedMethod method = (ReflectionBasedMethod)((MethodBasedOperation)operation).Method;
    MethodInfo methodInfo = method.MethodInfo;
```

For that to work, I had to add the 'Method' property to OpenRasta's ReflectionBasedMethod.

Can the same be accomplished without hacking OpenRasta (I'm on 2.0 btw)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the wrong question. What you're looking for is simply:

```
var attribute = operation.FindAttribute<EnforceParamAttribute>()
```

Downcasting is not supported and the operation should only reflect an operation and its inputs, on purpose. Do not downcast, it *will* break and your code is not guaranteed to work beyond one version that happens to use the IMethod API, which is going at some point to be rewritten / removed.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks. I went for FindAttributes (plural), as I can have multiple attributes of the same type. Which brought up an issue: When I have 2 EnforceParamAttributes on a method, BeforeExecute is called twice on the same interceptor, but as I don't the attribute instance on which BeforeExecute is called I will use FindAttributes to look at all attributes, so calling twice is not necessary. Any idea on how to get around this other than setting a flag "ranBefore" inside BeforeExecute?

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy: that's probably worth another question - and I'm sure serialseb will appreciate it if you accept his answer!

Comment: There shouldn't be an interceptor executing more than once if you registered it only once, is that what you're seeing?